# CSS Gradient - Not showing in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, gradient

I am looking to have a rainbow effect on a text. I have the following code which is working in all browsers except Internet Explorer.  Anyone familiar with how to get this to work in IE?

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/49orb1z2/)

HTML:

```
<span class="icon-child-work">
  Hello
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.icon-child-work {
  color: transparent;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0.5,        #f22), color-stop(0.10, #f2f), color-stop(0.20, #22f), color-stop(0.25, #2ff),   color-stop(0.30, #128C16),color-stop(0.40, #2f2), color-stop(0.45, #ff2), color-stop(0.55, #f2f) );
  background-image: gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0.5, #f22), color-stop(0.10, #f2f), color-stop(0.20, #22f), color-stop(0.25, #2ff), color-stop(0.30, #128C16),color-stop(0.40, #2f2), color-stop(0.45, #ff2), color-stop(0.55, #f2f) );
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient (GradientType=0, startColorstr=#1471da, endColorstr=#1C85FB)";

  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will address background gradients for older versions of IE but **not text**:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #feffff 0%,#1471da 50%,#1C85FB 100%); /* Supports IE10+ and several other older browsers */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1471da', endColorstr='#1C85FB',GradientType=0 ); /* Supports IE6-9 */
```

Comment: The gradient shows as background of the whole span.  I need it to filter through the text

Comment: Looks like I "misread" the question. What is the oldest version you need to support? I will update the answer.

Comment: Doh! So to support gradient text on older versions of IE, I don't think there is a filter equivalent. Are you open to using some JS?

Comment: Not opposed to it.

Comment: Go check this out. I've tested it on IE9 and it works fine. IE8 had an issue that arrose: http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/canvas_filltext.asp and then there is also a jquery plugin with decent IE coverage back to IE7 http://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-For-Text-Gradient-Effect-pxgradient.html